# How to check if the value is negative within the given time interval in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a value where I want to check if it is negative or 0 within the first 4 weeks from now.

```
Product ID  Quantity    Week Ending
A             5          18/07/2021
A            -6          25/07/2021
A             4          29/08/2021
B             2          18/07/2021
B             7          25/07/2021
```

For example for my sample dataset above, product A is negative within the first 4 weeks from now because it is negative on 25/07/2021. So I want to create a measure that gives me Yes or No based on the condition above for all products. In this case,

Finally, when I use the measure in matrix along with the product ID, It should give me result that resembles below:

```
Product ID    Is Short In 4 Weeks
A               Yes
B               No
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a measure with below code.

```
Negative_Check = 

    VAR result =
        CALCULATE (
            MIN ( 'Table (3)'[Quantity] ),
            FILTER (
                'Table (3)',
                'Table (3)'[Week Ending] >= TODAY ()
                    && 'Table (3)'[Week Ending]
                        <= TODAY () + 28
            )
        )
    RETURN
        IF ( result < 0, "Yes", "No" )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is perfectly working. Can you please also suggest how to get the earliest date where the product ID went negative.  For instance, in the matrix you displayed above, if  I can add date column and show 25/07/2021 and null for product B. Is that also possible please?

Comment: You can add 1 more measure with below code:-

Measure 5 = IF([Negative_Check] = "No",MAX('Table (3)'[Week Ending]))

Comment: I cant thank you enough for this. Yes, This works! :)